# What's the best way to monitor contract variables whilst developing?

Tags: truffle, remix

I'm running a contract locally using Truffle, is there a way I can keep track of the variables in real-time whilst interacting with it on the front-end (Web3). I guess what I'm looking for here is something similar to http://remix.ethereum.org.

Comment: Did you try running your local instance of remix? It has a github repository https://github.com/ethereum/browser-solidity.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, looks like the best solution for now.